# Uber Rides JAVA SDK : Unable to request token

Tags: java, google-app-engine, uber-api

I am new to using API in Java. I need to access Uber API's for my project and I am using Uber Java SDK from - https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk

I am following their steps but somehow getting error for Authenticating credentials. following are my steps:

1) Creating OAuth2Credentials object

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setClientSecret(MY_SECRET)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL)
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.HISTORY, Scope.PROFILE, Scope.PLACES))
                .build();

OAuth2Credentials credentials = new OAuth2Credentials.Builder()
                .setSessionConfiguration(config)
                .build();
```

2) Navigate the user to the authorization URL from the OAuth2Credentials object.

```
String authorizationUrl = credentials.getAuthorizationUrl();
```

3) Once the user approves the request, you get an authorization code. Create a credential object to store the authorization code and the user ID.

```
Credential credential = credentials.authenticate(authorizationCode, userId);
```

** i am using "authorizationCode" returned to my REDIRECT_URL
 ** I am NOT sure what userID should be??

But really code fails at STEP 3 with error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

    Unable to request token.
Caused by:

com.uber.sdk.rides.auth.AuthException: Unable to request token.
    at com.uber.sdk.rides.auth.OAuth2Credentials.authenticate(OAuth2Credentials.java:279)
    at com.c2p.HelloAppEngine.doGet(HelloAppEngine.java:183)
```

*** Please HELP:

1) How to resolve above error - am I doing anything wrong? 
2) Are my steps correct? 
3) What should be the UserID and where can i get that?

Comment: The userId is supposed to be a String that is used as a key to store the credentials in the underlying DataStore. More details can be found here: https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/rides/auth/OAuth2Credentials.java#L264. Looking at the error (line 279), it suggests that it was thrown by an IOException. Therefore, it appears to me that your issue is unrelated to the userId. Could you share your whole class/method for more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the user uuid you need to take the access token you get and make a request to https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-me.

```
UserProfile userProfile = uberRidesService.getUserProfile().execute().body();
```

See the java sample app included in the sdk: https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/blob/master/samples/servlet-sample/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/rides/samples/servlet/SampleServlet.java